# jQuery Custom Input trigger checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Custom-Input to style my checkboxes and it works fine. The problem occurs when i try to check that checkbox not by clicking on it, but by checking them with jquery with this:

```
$('#my_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

When i do this, the styled checkbox is not checked anymore. The unstyled (real one that is hidden) is checked.

Is there a solution for this? Thanks

Update:
Meanwhile i found a solution, witch is not very optimised:

```
$('#my_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
$('#my_checkbox').parent().find('label').addClass('checked');
```

First line checked the real checkbox, and the second line checkes the fictive checkbox. I hope there is a solution on 1 line to this problem. Still waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#my_checkbox').click();
```

Instead of:

```
$('#my_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

It should do what you expect.

Comment: You know, i tryed this also, and i don't know for what reason i didn't see that it worked. I was about to tell you that this is not working either, but i said to my self to test again and not throw conclusions that easy and after doing that, i saw that it works. Thanks

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora: You know, we've been there, done that millions of times. Part of coding :)